# Using jQuery getscript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

To ask about getscript

html Code as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "- / / W3C / / DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional / /
EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html>
    <head> 
        <title>jQuery GetScript</title> 
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
        <script type = "text / javascript "> 
            $(document). ready(function () {
                $getScript ('script.js', function (jd) {
                    $.each (test, function (index, value) {
                        console.log (value);
                    });
                });
            }); 
        </script> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <div id="dest"> </div> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

js (1) code are as follows: -

```
<script type='text/javascript'> var test = []; test [0] = ['111 ', '222']; </ script>
```

js (2) Code as follows: -

```
var test = []; test [0] = ['111 ', '222'];
```

The problem is as follows: -
Run js (1) code will appear: - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

No problem running js (2)

Would like to ask how we can run js (1) can not go wrong Thank!
Badly written, please forgive me.

Comment: I was going to fix this up for you - but you couldn't even be bothered to spell the title of your question correctly. Please click the edit button and fix this up. You can prepend code by four spaces or use the `{}` button to properly block your code.

Answer (score 1):

You should not include a `<script`> element in external javascript files.

js (1) Code should look like this:

```
var test = []; test [0] = ['111 ', '222'];
```

Comment: (Because `<script>` is HTML and not JavaScript)